# MVC5 ActionLink Wrong URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink

I've tried finding something similar to my problem, but am having a hard time. I'm trying to pass data from my view to a controller, but am getting the wrong URL passed through. From what I can tell the routing isn't the problem, but I don't know what is.

Here's my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Test", null, new { data_modal = "", id = 1, @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" })
```

And my routing setup:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Here is the link being sent:

```
http://localhost:49633/Test/Create?_=1421171966639
```

I cannot figure out why this is. I am passing from a view in the Home, Index view to a controller, "Test"... is this a problem?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the desired url formation you expected?

Comment: What do you want the url to be? If you want the id to be in the link don't you want to have @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Test", new {id = 1}, { data_modal = "",  @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" })

Comment: @TusharGupta I'm expecting:
http://localhost:49633/Test/Create/1

Comment: @tabz100 That worked perfectly, thanks for the response. After looking at this I can't believe I couldn't figure that out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the id in the link you need to pass the id as route values like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "Test", new {id = 1}, { data_modal = "", @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" })
```